# What is the difference between 'path' and 'query' in a API call

Tags: javascript

I m trying to implement faceit API in my website.There are two end points from which I can retieve a player's information

1.https://open.faceit.com/data/v4/players?nickname=DeADLY2501&game=CSGO&game_player_id=76561198806878477

This is the first way.Below i will link a image.From faceit documentation(https://developers.faceit.com/docs/tools/data-api)

[image]

Here there is a parameter called 'game_player_id' which says it must be a string and 'query'.

Here is the second endpoint

[image]

Here in which a parameter is need called 'player_id' which is required needs to be a string and must be a 'path'.
Can some one please tell me what is the difference.Because in the first end point.We need 'nickname','game' and 'game_player_id'.
I just want to retrive a players information just from the id,So that can be made possible by the second endpoint.The problem is that.With the same 'player_id',I send calls for both end points.The first one sends a response successfuly.While the second endpoint says 'Not Found'.I gather that it might be that the type of parameter im making the request with are not proper for the 2nd endpoint.

Any help regarding this is appriciated thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a formal definition [here](https://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/5_BNF.html)

But sometimes it's easier to see an example, consider `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62362966/?arg=3;other=word` This is composed of several parts:

- `https` - this is the **scheme**
- `stackoverflow.com` - this is the **hostname**
- `questions/62362966/` - this is the **path**
- `arg=3;other=word` - this is the **query**

Note that where your documentation above refers to a value appearing in a path or query, that does not mean it exclusively constitutes the path or query - there is also data/meta-data framing it.

Answer (score 0):

Path and query - different parts of the URL. Basically, everything that goes after `?` is query, everything between domain and `?` is path.

See details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL)

Answer (score 0):

A query goes after `?` **AND** is made up of a key and a value in the form `key=value`. Each pair is separeted by a `&`.

A path is what goes after the first slash (`/`) and before `?`. It doesn't require the key-value pattern. You just put the **value** in the right spot (i.e. between other slashes).

Answer (score 0):

In example below I mean the `user_id` is a path.

```
https://www.example.com/api/v2/users/{user_id}

https://www.example.com/api/v2/users/11
```

In example below I mean the `limit` and the `page` is a query.

```
https://www.example.com/api/v2/users?limit={limit_value}&page={limit_value}

https://www.example.com/api/v2/users?limit=50&page=1
```